# Including a sub-view in the parent

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.1, laravel-blade

I am trying to include a 'item' sub-view in the 'show' view

'show' is like this:

```
@extends('layout/layoutWhite')

@section('content')
    Text1
    @include('publicSurvey.item')
    Text2
@stop
```

and 'item' view

```
@section('content')
@parent
Text3
@stop
```

And the problem is that I need Text3 to be in between Text1 and Text2 but instead it is in the end of the parent view.

Comment: You’d be better off just creating two sections instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just omit the section definition in your subview. Including doesn't require a section it will just simply replace the include line with the content of the subview.

So your subview should only contain the content:

```
Text3
```

Comment: I already tried that before and it didn't work, it didn't show the subview, but now it does.. Well thank you, I don't know what was the issue when i tried it before then.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is change your `item` view to `Text3`.

`@include('publicSurvey.item')` get all codes in `publicSurvey.item` instead this line.

Comment: That is exactly the same thing what I wrote 5 hours before you.

Answer (score 0):

```
+home
  -index.blade.php
+admin
  -login.blade.php
```

You can extend index.blade.php in login.blade.php using

```
  @extends('../home.index')
```